# Remove characters from an element while using appendChild

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove or replace characters in an element while using appendChild as follow:

```
var options = from.getElementsByTagName("option");

var to = document.getElementById("target");

to.appendChild(options[i].replace("(A)",""));
```

I tried various different syntax but no luck. Can someone help? Either JQuery or javascript works for me.

Thanks

Comment: options[i].innerHTML?

Comment: It `from` supposed to be `form` by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're already in a `for` loop. If so, use the `.text` property of the `option` element, and create a new text node.

```
to.appendChild(document.createTextNode(options[i].text.replace("(A)","")));
```

Or better, in the loop append to a string, and create a single node at the end.

```
var txt = "":
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; ++i)
    txt += options[i].text.replace("(A)"), "");
}
to.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
```

---

If you actually wanted to append a copy of the element itself, then use `.cloneNode(true)` instead.

```
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; ++i) {
    var clone = to.appendChild(options[i].cloneNode(true));
    clone.text = clone.text.replace("(A)", "");
}
```